# Combine tables only if no results

Tags: sql-server-2005

We have a table `FOO` that has a huge amount of data in it, most of which is only used infrequently and by (slow) user-interaction.

We would like to move all data that is more than 12 months old to an archive table, `FOO_ARCHIVE`. That will make the frequent reads and writes into `FOO` fast enough.

There are many complex stored procedures in our application(s) that currently query against `FOO`, so we need a way to sensibly combine the two tables when reporting.

I have considered using a union, but I'd rather only look in the archive table if I need to, which is when nothing is in the live table.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, FieldN FROM FOO
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, FieldN FROM FOO_ARCHIVE
```

However, I'd rather only hit archive if I have to, so perhaps create a stored procedure for this:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, FieldN FROM FOO
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, FieldN FROM FOO_ARCHIVE
END
```

But I only want one result set returned, and there can be many conditions applied to the query.

The solution must be supportable on SQL Server 2005, due to client deployments.

Comment: Are you using standard or enterprise version of sql 2005 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't say "UNION ALL ONLY IF SOME CONDITION" but you could do:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.FOO)
BEGIN
  SELECT Column1, Column2, ColumnN FROM dbo.FOO;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM dbo.FOO_ARCHIVE;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Enterprise i would look at a [partitioned table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188706%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

If not I would look at a [partitioned view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Using a partitioned table or partitioned view would help your application by allowing the query optimizer to ignore parts of the table that it does not need based on the where clause.  Choosing the partitioning key is the key to making the access to the table very fast.

The question i have is would you every have queries that use data from both the last 12 months and from before that time?  The best way is to partition the data in the table with one of the above methods as you will not loose access to any of your data in the single table (or view) FOO and you would get the benefit of being able to limit what part of the data is accessed because of the partitioning.